# Any way of show hide multiple passwords at the same time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, dom

I am trying to find a solution if is possible to show / hide the password at the same time?

I could only show / hide for the first original password. 
Does anybody know a solution for it or if is even possible?

Here is JavaScript and HTML code

```js
function Toggle() {
  let btt = password
  if (btt.type === "password") {
    btt.type = "text";
  } else {
    btt.type = "password";
  }
}

function checkPassword(register) { //correct
  let fisrtPassword = register.password.value;
  let retypedPassword = register.retypedpassword.value;
  if (fisrtPassword === retypedPassword) {
    return true;
  } else {
    passwordMatchError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    passwordMatchError.innerHTML = ("Passwords do not match. Please retype");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean the code that changes from password to text and back?

Comment: Yes.. I've done the code to show the text of the original password, but I don't know how to show the text of the second password that is perhaps matching with the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Toggle` function you are currently only updating the field with the id `password`. So when you change the type of that field, only that field is changed. You are not checking the other field called `retypedpassword`, therefor it won't be changed. Check out the my addition to your code here below for a working version of your toggle for BOTH fields.

```js
function Toggle() {
    const fields = [password, retypedpassword]

    fields.forEach( x => {
        if (x.type === "password") {
            x.type = "text";
        } else {
            x.type = "password";
        }
    });
}
```

And a second exmample using the style of your current code:

```js
function Toggle() {
    let btt = password
    if (btt.type === "password") {
        btt.type = "text";
    } else {
        btt.type = "password";
    }

    let otherfield = retypedpassword
    if (otherfield.type === "password") {
        otherfield.type = "text";
    } else {
        otherfield.type = "password";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah because I was only using one type of the field it wasn't working for the others. I see now. very useful. works for me. thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Note I remove the toggle from the password field click and gave the fields a class

I also streamlined your submit handler and fixed spelling and added required

```js
document.getElementById("showpasswords").addEventListener("click",function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".password")].forEach(p =>
    p.type = p.type === "password" ? "text" : "password"
  )
})
document.getElementById("registerdetails").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  const errSpan = document.getElementById("passwordmatcherror");
  let firstPassword = this.password.value;
  let retypedPassword = this.retypedpassword.value;
  errSpan.classList.toggle("error", firstPassword !== retypedPassword);

  if (firstPassword !== retypedPassword) {
    errSpan.innerHTML = ("Passwords do not match. Please retype");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="formcontainer">
    <form id="registerdetails" action="fma_t3confirm.html">
      <div>
        <label for="password">* Password (Must be 8 characters and include one uppercase, one lowercase and
      one numeric):</label><br/>
        <input type="password" class="password" id="password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,8}$" required>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="showpasswords"> Show passwords</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="retypedpassword">* Retype your password:</label><br/>
        <input type="password" class="password" id="retypedpassword">
        <span id="passwordmatcherror"></span>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect code. I enjoyed to see the different way to execute the code without having to use the Toggle from the password field. for some reason is not working, probably something in my code.. will check that out. I appreciate. really helpful.

Comment: May I ask you. Do you know if is possible to add a required in JS? or is only in html

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is just adding another button for the second input:

```
function Toggle() {
    let btt = password;
    let btt2 = retypedpassword;

    if (btt.type === "password") {
        btt.type = "text";
        btt2.type = "text";
    } else {
        btt.type = "password";
        btt2.type = "password";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also great. I was almost close to your code. thanks to share your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `pwd` in both password fields. Also remove the Toggle method call on click of 2nd password field

```
<input type="password" class="pwd" id="password" 
                                       pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,8}$">
<input type="password" class="pwd" id="retypedpassword">
```

Your Toggle function:
In the Toggle function, get all the pwd fields and then toggle the type of all fileds.

```
  function Toggle() {
    let pwdFiels = document.querySelectorAll('.pwd');

    for (let fields in pwdFiels) {
        if (pwdFiels[fields].type === "password") {
            pwdFiels[fields].type = "text";
        } else {
            pwdFiels[fields].type = "password";
        }
    }
}
```